# SSRS Change cell color depending on SUM value

Tags: sql, if-statement, reporting-services, sum, cell

I am loading a dataset into my report and filling my last column with this expression: =Sum(Fields!ID.Value) and it loads fine, I am trying to put a condition in so when the number is less than 15 for example, the cell color will change to red. I have tried so many different syntax but nothing works... it must be pretty simple...?
The errors I am getting are: The value expression for textbox has scope parameter that is invalid for aggregate

Any help would be good :)

Comment: Is your textbox which is used for displaying the sum is in the same group ? If yes then just try to closing and reopening the studio. If not then use the scope parameter with the `sum` function

Comment: =Sum(Fields!ID.Value < 15, "Red")... is this syntax correct?

Comment: This is wrong syntax see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the background color Click on the cell and in properties window on your right hand select the `BackgroundColor` property and then set expression to that property.
Or right click on cell and select `TextboxProperties` -> `Fill` and at the start there is option to set the expression for fill color.
You are using the wrong expression the expression should be ,

```
  = IIF(Sum(Fields!ID.Value) < 15,"Red","Transparent")
```

You can change the `Transparent` to whatever color you want.[Take a look here on how to use expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx).

Comment: That just changes the value of the cell to "Red" etc.

Comment: Don't set this in the value expression. Click on the cell and in properties window on your right hand select the `BackgroundColor` property and then set expression to that property

Comment: Or right click on cell and select `TextboxProperties` -> `Fill` and at the start there is option to set the expression for fill color.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help, first time using SSRS!

Answer (score 1):

This shows how you could add a colour range if necessary by using the Color property to set the font colour.

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!ID.Value) < 15,"Red",iif(Sum(Fields!ID.Value)>50,"Blue","Black"))
```

To Change the background colour instead you would use the Background colour property.

```
 =iif(Sum(Fields!ID.Value) < 15,"Red", "No Color")
```

Note that SSRS 2008 "Transaparent" is replaced by "No Color". Whilst transaparent works it gives rise to this warning message.

[rsInvalidColor] The value of the BackgroundColor property for the textbox ‘textbox22’ is “Transparent”, which is not a valid BackgroundColor.

As an alternative to these use "#FFFFFF" instead of Transaparent or No Color

Comment: What this expressiion has to do with the OP ?

Comment: Shows the general principle of getting a field value to change colour

Comment: No it is not. It just shows you just copy pasted this from somewhere else .

Comment: Correct why is that a problem? It still provides enough information for the questioner to work out what to do

Comment: Th OP being newbie he doesn't even know how to set the background color you are bombarding him with the  nested `IIF` expression without giving any explanation what so ever.

Comment: I have modified my original answer to make it more informative